# too many open sockets with HttpClient?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have the following code in client of http-client 4.2.1

```
    PoolingClientConnectionManager mgr = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
    mgr.setMaxTotal(20);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr);
```

I then have a try...finally and call httpPost.reset after every post.

For some reason, I see the program taking up 110 ESTABLISHED http connections to my server and 235 connections in CLOSE_WAIT(not TIMED_WAIT).

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a bug around this?  The maximum connections should be 20 or am I mistaken?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, never mind....someone was creating quite a few DefaultHttpClient's in the code and I had missed that.  It seems to be working now except now it keeps creating new sockets over and over for the same host(different urls on same host) resulting in a performance nightmare of very slow throughput :(....grrrrrr.